# Need group jobs in lumen framework

Tags: php, laravel, queue, lumen

I have a scheduled process that need to prepare a bunch of jobs together for notification on end. Looking on Laravel documentation i fund that you can Job Batching. But apparently not in lumen, or at least is what i thought because i keep recive error during the dispach of the batch.
Following the doc i write the following:

```
/*scheduled_proc*/

info('start job');

Bus::batch([
    new TestJob(1),
    new TestJob(2),
    new TestJob(3),
    new TestJob(4),
    new TestJob(5),
])
->then(function(Batch $batch){
    info('end job');

})
->catch(function (Batch $batch, Throwable $e) {
    report($e);
})
->onQueue('my_queue')
->allowFailures()
->dispatch();



______________________
TestJob.php


namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Batchable;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class TestJob implements ShouldQueue
{

    use Batchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private $num;
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($num)
    {
        $this->num = $num;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        if ($this->batch()->cancelled()) {
            Log::error('Job cancelled');
            return;
        }
        info('num'.$num);
    }
}
```

but i recive an error during the dispatch method

```
Serialization of 'PDO' is not allowed {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Serialization of 'PDO' is not allowed at /var/www/html/vendor/opis/closure/src/SerializableClosure.php:155)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/opis/closure/src/SerializableClosure.php(155): serialize(Array)
#1 [internal function]: Opis\\Closure\\SerializableClosure->serialize()
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/illuminate/bus/DatabaseBatchRepository.php(302): serialize(Array)
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/illuminate/bus/DatabaseBatchRepository.php(106): Illuminate\\Bus\\DatabaseBatchRepository->serialize(Array)
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/illuminate/bus/PendingBatch.php(239): Illuminate\\Bus\\DatabaseBatchRepository->store(Object(Illuminate\\Bus\\PendingBatch))
#5 the call of Bus::dispatch()
#6 ....
```

The queue driver is database and i've done the tables and migrate the db.
Now on the doc of Lumen i read '***Note: Closure jobs are not supported by Lumen.***', is this the case?
In **Lumen**, how can i group together a bunch of jobs so i can do something when are all done?

Comment: did you achieve in any way? i am in the same case, i need batch jobs

Comment: @EduardoHernandez. Nope. Lumen don't have the code for batch Job. But i worked around it with chain. $masterJob->chain([$job1, $job2, $job3])

Comment: after investigating, yeah it has, but in versions higher than 8

Comment: @Lorenzo chaining is VERY different from batching: if you chain and one job fails, subsequent jobs will NOT be run.